# Setting Datetime field using Ruby Form helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, form-helpers

I am trying to set a datetime field using the ruby forum helpers.

```
<%= form_for @event  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <strong>Title</strong>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title  %>
  </div>
  <strong>Description</strong>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => "comment" %>
  </div>
  <strong>Location</strong>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :location  %>
  </div>
  <strong>Time</strong>
  <div class="field">
    <%= select_datetime Date.today, :prefix => :start_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Event" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the controller I am doing this:
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @event = Event.new
  end

```
  def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
    if @event.save
      redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success => "#{@event.inspect}!" }
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
end
```

However the date time never sets...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process what you're getting in your controller, like:

```
def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
    datetime=DateTime.civil(params[:start_date][:year].to_i, params[:start_date][:month].to_i, params[:start_date][:day].to_i,
                            params[:start_date][:hours].to_i,params[:start_date][:minutes].to_i, params[:start_date][:seconds].to_i)
    @event.datetime = datetime
    if @event.save
      redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success => "#{@event.inspect}!" }
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I was hoping to also get hours and minutes inserted as well. This only takes into account days, years and months.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost half a decade old but just in case it helps someone in future, there's a simpler way to create objects of a model with datetime attribute.

Replace `<%= select_datetime Date.today, :prefix => :start_date %>` with `<%= f.datetime_select :datetime %>`

And define the create action in controller as below.

```
def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
    if @event.save
      redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success => "#{@event.inspect}!" }
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
end
```